# heroku error with newrelic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, newrelic

I have this weird error after I setup new relic to my heroku app. It worked great before but now it gives me this error - does someone have a clue? It sends me to heroku 500 error page and the attached code is from heroku logs.

```
    Sep 07 02:11:10 gyms heroku/router:  at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=gyms.herokuapp.com fwd="50.31.164.139" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=36ms status=200 bytes=0 
Sep 07 02:11:27 gyms heroku/router:  at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=gyms.herokuapp.com fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=0 
Sep 07 02:11:48 gyms heroku/router:  at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=gyms.herokuapp.com fwd="50.18.57.7" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=0 
Sep 07 02:12:12 gyms heroku/api:  Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by sabatsuk@gmail.com 
Sep 07 02:12:18 gyms heroku/api:  Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by sabatsuk@gmail.com 
Sep 07 02:12:24 gyms heroku/router:  at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=gyms.herokuapp.com fwd="184.73.237.85" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=0 
Sep 07 02:12:29 gyms heroku/run.9767:  Awaiting client 
Sep 07 02:12:30 gyms heroku/run.2092:  Awaiting client 
Sep 07 02:12:30 gyms heroku/run.2092:  Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` 
Sep 07 02:12:34 gyms heroku/run.2092:  Process exited with status 0 
Sep 07 02:12:34 gyms heroku/run.2092:  State changed from up to complete 
Sep 07 02:12:39 gyms heroku/run.9767:  Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds 
Sep 07 02:12:39 gyms heroku/run.9767:  Stopping process with SIGKILL 
Sep 07 02:12:40 gyms heroku/run.9767:  State changed from starting to complete 
Sep 07 02:12:43 gyms app/web.1:  Started GET "/memberships" for 109.65.193.237 at 2013-09-07 09:12:42 +0000 
Sep 07 02:12:43 gyms heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path=/memberships host=gyms.herokuapp.com fwd="109.65.193.237" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=643 
Sep 07 02:12:43 gyms app/web.1:  NoMethodError (undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass): 
Sep 07 02:12:43 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:145:in `detail_args_for' 
Sep 07 02:12:43 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find' 
Sep 07 02:12:43 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `find_template' 
Sep 07 02:12:44 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.5.4.34/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:153:in `render_with_newrelic' 
Sep 07 02:12:44 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template' 
Sep 07 02:12:44 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render' 
Sep 07 02:12:44 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template' 
Sep 07 02:12:44 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:34:in `determine_template' 
Sep 07 02:12:44 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template' 
Sep 07 02:12:44 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body' 
Sep 07 02:12:44 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body' 
Sep 07 02:12:44 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body' 
Sep 07 02:12:45 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render' 
Sep 07 02:12:45 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render' 
Sep 07 02:12:45 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms' 
Sep 07 02:12:45 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime' 
Sep 07 02:12:45 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render' 
Sep 07 02:12:45 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms' 
Sep 07 02:12:45 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render' 
Sep 07 02:12:45 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime' 
Sep 07 02:12:45 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime' 
Sep 07 02:12:46 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:232:in `default_render' 
Sep 07 02:12:46 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:160:in `to_html' 
Sep 07 02:12:46 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/responders-1.0.0.rc/lib/responders/flash_responder.rb:104:in `to_html' 
Sep 07 02:12:46 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:153:in `respond' 
Sep 07 02:12:46 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:146:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:46 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:239:in `respond_with' 
Sep 07 02:12:46 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/inherited_resources-1.4.1/lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:7:in `index' 
Sep 07 02:12:46 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action' 
Sep 07 02:12:46 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action' 
Sep 07 02:12:46 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action' 
Sep 07 02:12:47 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action' 
Sep 07 02:12:47 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__647810640918505021__process_action__383065631445966333__callbacks' 
Sep 07 02:12:47 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback' 
Sep 07 02:12:47 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks' 
Sep 07 02:12:47 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks' 
Sep 07 02:12:47 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action' 
Sep 07 02:12:47 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument' 
Sep 07 02:12:48 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument' 
Sep 07 02:12:48 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument' 
Sep 07 02:12:48 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action' 
Sep 07 02:12:48 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action' 
Sep 07 02:12:48 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action' 
Sep 07 02:12:48 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.5.4.34/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:34:in `block in process_action' 
Sep 07 02:12:48 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.5.4.34/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:268:in `block in perform_action_with_newrelic_trace' 
Sep 07 02:12:48 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.5.4.34/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:242:in `trace_execution_scoped' 
Sep 07 02:12:48 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.5.4.34/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:263:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace' 
Sep 07 02:12:48 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.5.4.34/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:33:in `process_action' 
Sep 07 02:12:49 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process' 
Sep 07 02:12:49 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch' 
Sep 07 02:12:49 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch' 
Sep 07 02:12:49 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action' 
Sep 07 02:12:49 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:49 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch' 
Sep 07 02:12:49 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:49 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call' 
Sep 07 02:12:49 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each' 
Sep 07 02:12:50 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:50 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:50 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.5.4.34/lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:8:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:50 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.5.4.34/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:12:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:50 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call' 
Sep 07 02:12:50 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch' 
Sep 07 02:12:50 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:50 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:50 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:51 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:51 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:51 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:51 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context' 
Sep 07 02:12:51 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:51 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:51 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:51 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call' 
Sep 07 02:12:51 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4253927515509182332__call__656494683648414723__callbacks' 
Sep 07 02:12:52 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback' 
Sep 07 02:12:52 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks' 
Sep 07 02:12:52 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks' 
Sep 07 02:12:52 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:52 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:52 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:52 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app' 
Sep 07 02:12:52 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call' 
Sep 07 02:12:53 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged' 
Sep 07 02:12:53 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:53 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:53 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:53 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:53 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:53 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward' 
Sep 07 02:12:53 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch' 
Sep 07 02:12:54 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup' 
Sep 07 02:12:54 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!' 
Sep 07 02:12:54 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:54 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:54 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:54 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:54 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call' 
Sep 07 02:12:54 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service' 
Sep 07 02:12:54 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service' 
Sep 07 02:12:54 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run' 
Sep 07 02:12:55 gyms app/web.1:    vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread' 
Sep 07 02:12:55 gyms app/web.1:  Processing by MembershipsController#index as HTML 
Sep 07 02:12:55 gyms app/web.1:  Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
```

Comment: I work for New Relic tech support and I'm sorry to hear that it's causing you trouble. We'd love to help you out, but we'll need additional info in order to do that. I'd suggest opening up a support ticket with New Relic so we can take a deeper look into your account and environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with some other gems. Try removing your Gemfile.lock and running bundle install. After that, commit Gemfile.lock and push again.